# Infinite Scrolling With limited fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is there anyway to create a limited `Fragment` + `ViewPager` with Infinite Scrolling?

For example :

I am going to create 10 `Fragment`, when I scroll to the fifth `Fragment`, index number 0 Fragment destroyed and appear the eleventh `Fragment`

```
**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

after scroll to the fifth

```
2 3 4 **5** 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

*Variable*

```
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 10;
```

Here is my `Fragment adapter`

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.create(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }

}
```

Here is the contain of the `Fragment` to show begin with number 1

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_view, container, false);

    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername)).setText(
            ""+ (mPageNumber + 1));
    return rootView;
}
```

Here is when the selected event occur

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pageSelected) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "selected = " + pageSelected);
        if (pageSelected > (NUM_PAGES - 6)) {
                   //Event do it here?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

**Question** :
How to create the event?

I think that can be done with changing the `position` value in the `getItem()`.
But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could come up with is to make only three pages and when the user scrolls to the last page, you replace every fragment. Something like this:

The array

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void initPositions() {
    positions.add(0);
    positions.add(1);
    positions.add(2);
}
```

The adapter

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.create(positions.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

}

The listener

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int pageSelected) {
        //scrolled to first page
        if(pageSelected == 0) {
                    //Make sure its not unlimited upwards
                    if(positions.get(pageSelected == 0))
                        return;
                    //remove last and insert new at bottom
            positions.remove(2);
            positions.insert(0, positions.get(0) - 1);
        //scrolled to last page
        } else if(pageSelected == 2) {
                    //remove first and add one last
            positions.remove(0);
            positions.add((positions.get(1) + 1) % NUM_PAGES);
        }
            //make sure the adapter understands
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //move pager to the middle again
            mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });
```

Not sure how this would work performancewise, or if it would work at all, but give it a shot :)

Comment: there is no insert() function for ArrayList, may I know how you do that?